# HC can not connect to DC for EAP7.1

Tags: jboss-eap-7

I installed eap7.1 by unzip the zip file on RHEL73, but failed to start host control to connect with domain controller, here is detail:
domain controller runs on node1:

```
/opt/jboss-eap-7.1/bin/domain.sh --host-config=host-master.xml -Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.56.11
Log:
[Host Controller] 10:53:53,258 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYRMT0001: Listening on 192.168.56.81:9999
```

Start host controller on node2:

```
/opt/jboss-eap-7.1/bin/domain.sh --host-config=host-slave.xml -Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.56.127 -Djboss.domain.master.address=192.168.56.11
```

I added remotehost1 by using add-user.sh on node1.
I added the authentication info in host-slave.xml on node2:

```
            <server-identities>
                <secret value="cmVkaGF0MUA="/>
            </server-identities>
...
<domain-controller>
   <remote security-realm="ManagementRealm" username="remotehost1">
```

host-controller failed startup with the following error:

```
10:57:17,068 WARN  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYHC0001: Could not connect to remote domain controller remote://192.168.56.81:9999: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to remote://192.168.56.81:9999. The connection timed out
...
ERROR [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYHC0002: Could not connect to master. Error was: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYHC0120: Tried all domain controller discovery option(s) but unable to connect.
```

netstat -an|grep 9999 show it's listening on 192.168.56.11(node1 public interface)

I stopped iptables, firewalled and selinux, I used nc -v 192.168.56.11 9999 and verified the address is accessable from node2, what could be the reason for this?

Best regards

Lan

Comment: You need to connect using 9990 port (http interface) you need to change jboss.domain.master.protocol to "http-remoting" in HC/host.xml as below:
...
<discovery-options>
<static-discovery name="primary" protocol="${jboss.domain.master.protocol:http-remoting}" host="${jboss.domain.master.address}" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9990}"/>
</discovery-options>
...
Make the above the changes and check whether HC connects to DC using 9990 port.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed.
The test is based on 2 guest VMs runing on window10 as host, windows 10 was restarted and I didn't notice that the firewall on windows was opened after restart, the VM uses host-only adapter to communication with each other, after disable firewall on windows, the communication works.